# super.init() recursive issue in Swift

Tags: swift, initialization, sprite-kit, subclass

I am working on a SpriteKit game using Swift and I need to subclass SKSpriteNode. In the init() (which is not an override) function I initialize the subclass's properties then call the super:

```
init(selector: Selector, delegateScene: SKScene, text: String, position: CGPoint) {
    self.delegateScene = delegateScene

    self.labelNode = SKLabelNode()
    self.labelNode.position = CGPointZero
    self.labelNode.text = text

    self.selector = selector

    super.init()
}
```

I set a breakpoint at the super.init() and a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION exception occurs right after it at the beginning of the subclass's init. Here's the error:

> (file path).swift: 12: 7: fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(texture:color:size:)' for class 'Energies.Button'

Comment: Do you use the latest version of Xcode (GM), which was released yesterday?

Comment: @GuidoHendriks yes, indeed, I do.

Comment: Is it correct that you're trying to get a node with a label? Does it have an image or texture as well?

Comment: @GuidoHendriks Yes, I am. It doesn't any image or texture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inherit from `SKSpriteNode`, you should call the designated initializer. In this case that needs to be `init(texture:color:size:)`. So if you were using a image or texture, you would need to call `super.init` like this:

```
super.init(texture: texture, color: nil, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
```

Note that you'll also need to set a size when initializing.

But in this case you can forget the above, because you're not looking for a subclass of `SKSpriteNode`, but a subclass of `SKNode`. If you change the superclass in the declaration from `SKSpriteNode` to `SKNode` it should work immediately.

You'll also need to add your add your label to the node after `super.init()`, else your label wouldn't be shown and your node would be empty.

Comment: I actually just right now, changed the superclass to SKNode and it worked. I was about to post the answer myself. Thank you for your help!